# the sum of all odd is sholud be 19 but it shows undefined?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

Why the answer is undefined here i cant understand that i am trying to find 
sum of odd numbers here  the answer should be 19 but it shows

```
enter code here
 function oddSum(arr){
 var sum =0;
 for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
  if(arr[i]%2>0)
   sum +=arr[i];`enter code here`
   return sum;
   }
   }

   document.write(oddSum([5,4,6,13,1]));
```

Comment: You are returning inside the `for` loop, which means you only return the first value. I

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code as below. Your mistake was you are returning the sum inside the for loop. That way you'll never get a correct sum. Also, try to use brackets even if there is only a single statement in an if clause. Then you can easily debug it.

```
function oddSum(arr){
    var sum =0;
    for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
        if(arr[i]%2>0){
            sum +=arr[i];
        }
    }
    return sum;
}
document.write(oddSum([5,4,6,13,1]));
```

Answer (score 0):

Just tip check array function reduce (https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/reduce).

And you will be able to do things like this:

```
console.log([5,4,6,13,1].reduce((a,b) => b % 2 !== 0 ? a + b : a, 0))
```